# How to pass props to grand child in svelte?

Tags: svelte

In svelte I want to pass down a prop value to a a grand child component. Unfortunately is it alway null. Why is it null?

**root component**

```
<script>
 import FirstChild from "./FirstChild.svelte"
 let amount = 3;
</script>
<My {amount} />
```

**First Child component**

```
 <script>
    import MyChild from "./MyChild.svelte"
    export let amount = null;
    
    $: {
        console.log("amount child", amount); // 3
    }
</script>
<MyChild />
```

**Grand child component**

```
<script>
    export let amount = null;
    
    $: {
        console.log("amount grandchild", amount); // null
    }
</script>
<p>
    My amount is {amount}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the prop to the component on the first child component to the grandchild. So:

**First child component:**

```
 <script>
    import MyChild from "./MyChild.svelte"
    export let amount = null;
    
    $: {
        console.log("amount child", amount); // 3
    }
</script>
<MyChild {amount} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a value available to descendant components you can use [`setContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) and [`getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-getcontext). Any context is available in any descendant without passing properties.